# Flutter md link not loading md file

Tags: flutter

I am using the flutter_markdown widget to display help info in my app.

Inside an md file I am using the link to another md file.  Both md files are defined in the 'assets' list in the pubspec.yml file

```
### [Overview](resource:asset/doc/overview.md) / Match Screen ###
```

Then I'm using the 'onTapLink' event handler to capture the users tap on the link to reset the markup widget to display the new md file like...

```
  Future<String> _getData(String aFileName) async{
   return rootBundle.loadString(aFileName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // get
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: _dataFuture,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Markdown(data: snapshot.data!, onTapLink: (text,href,title) {
                setState(()  {
                  _dataFuture = _getData(href!);
                });

              },);
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

However, the onTapLnk code is causing an exception where it can't load the md file name passed in 'hef'

```
E/flutter ( 7261): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: resource:asset/doc/overview.md
E/flutter ( 7261): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
E/flutter ( 7261): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7261): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:72:27)
E/flutter ( 7261): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7261):
```

Any suggestions?

Through testing I can separately display both md files,  so its nothing to do with faulty asset definition in the pubspec.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

The link definition in the md file should be

```
### [Overview](asset/doc/overview.md) / Match Screen ###
```

not

```
### [Overview](resource:asset/doc/overview.md) / Match Screen ###
```